# wx.grid.Grid using too much space within wx.BoxSizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm trying to display a table of items in wxpython using a wx.grid.Grid() inside a wx.BoxSizer. The table is large but I didn't want it to take up all the screen space so I put it in the boxsizer as shown in the code below.

```
def setOutputPanel(self):
    self.outputBox = wx.grid.Grid(parent=self.pnl)
    self.outputBox.CreateGrid(100, 100)
    self.outputBox.DisableCellEditControl()
    self.outputPanel.Add(self.outputBox, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.graphControl = wx.Button(parent=self.pnl, label="close")
    self.outputPanel.Add(self.graphControl, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    self.outputText = wx.TextCtrl(parent=self.pnl, value="text control", style=wx.EXPAND)
    self.outputPanel.Add(self.outputText, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

The problem is that when I put the size for the outputText to 1

```
self.outputPanel.Add(self.outputText, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

It doesn't show at all
[link to TextCtrl@size1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YggEX.png)

I can get it to show if I set the size to 0.

```
self.outputPanel.Add(self.outputText, 0, wx.EXPAND)
```

But, it's far too small. I'd like it to be the same height at the table. [link to TextCtrl@size0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUdIO.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, after reading some more of the wxPython documentation I have found the solution.

If you go to [this page](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Sizer.html), where they discuss some of the wxPython sizer features (the super class for `wx.BoxSizer`). On the page it says "Normally `wx.Sizers` will use `wx.Window.GetEffectiveMinSize` to determine what the minimal size of window items should be, and will use that size to calculate the layout." so I added the `wx.FIXED_MINSIZE` and now the grid doesn't have a minimum size.

This might seem like a bad idea as the grid can now shrink to a size that's too small. But, I've set the frame min size pretty large and the grid uses half the space, so I don't think It's going to be an issue.